# Gear Fit 2 - CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED

Tags: certificate, tizen

We have been developing for Gear Fit 2 during the last 4 months using Tizen Studio 1.2 and haven't have any problems with CERTIFICATES until the 8th January 2018, when we received the update to Studio 2.1.

Now it's impossible to install any of our Apps to the Gear Fit 2 because we get an installation error in the Wristband (CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED).

All the GEars have the updated Firmware (R360XXU1DQE6) and we have reinstalled Tizen Studio 1.2, 1.3 and 2.1 and generated CERTIFICATES with the corresponding Certificate Manager tool in each release of Tizen Studio. Also we have made a Factory reset to all the units we are using for our project(15xGearFit2).
We have obtained the same error using all the releases of Tizen Studio in MACOS 10.10.5 and Windows 10.

The error we get for all the apps a we have tried (include the samples included in Tizen Studio) is:

```
[Deploying the package...]
RDS: On
[Creating the package...]
Created the package: /Users/delacal/workspace/BasicUI/Debug/org.example.basicui-1.0.0-arm.tpk
[Transferring the package...]
Transferred the package: /Users/delacal/workspace/BasicUI/Debug/org.example.basicui-1.0.0-arm.tpk -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp
[Installing the package...]
Uninstalling the package...
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/org.example.basicui-1.0.0-arm.tpk
start process (install)
.
error : 34

end process (fail)
processing result : CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED [34] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [3578]ms
cmd_ret:34
(7.407 sec)
```

Has any pleople the same problem?

Thank very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://wiki.tizen.org/SDK#error_:_34_:_CERTIFICATE_EXPIRED), this issue occurs due to date & time mismatch between PC and development device. Updating date and time on device is supposed to solve this.